# Arduino Uno - How to write personal data in NTAG213 using RFID-RC522

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

I am trying to write some data in NTAG213 sticker with this code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

constexpr uint8_t RST_PIN = 9;     // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
constexpr uint8_t SS_PIN = 10;     // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);        // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  SPI.begin();               // Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();        // Init MFRC522 card
  Serial.println(F("Write personal data on a MIFARE PICC "));
}

void loop() {

// Prepare key - all keys are set to FFFFFFFFFFFFh at chip delivery from the factory.
  MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;
  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;

  // Look for new cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
   return;
}

// Select one of the cards
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
  return;
}

Serial.print(F("Card UID:"));    //Dump UID
for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
   Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
   Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
}
Serial.print(F(" PICC type: "));   // Dump PICC type
MFRC522::PICC_Type piccType = mfrc522.PICC_GetType(mfrc522.uid.sak);
Serial.println(mfrc522.PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));

byte buffer[34];
byte block;
MFRC522::StatusCode status;
byte len;

 Serial.setTimeout(20000L) ;     // wait until 20 seconds for input from serial
 // Ask personal data: Family name
 Serial.println(F("Type Family name, ending with #"));
 len = Serial.readBytesUntil('#', (char *) buffer, 30) ; // read family name from serial
 for (byte i = len; i < 30; i++) buffer[i] = ' ';     // pad with spaces

 block = 1;
 //Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
 status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
 if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
   Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
   Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
   return;
 }
 else Serial.println(F("PCD_Authenticate() success: "));

 // Write block
 status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(block, buffer, 16);
 if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
   Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Write() failed: "));
   Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
   return;
 }
 else Serial.println(F("MIFARE_Write() success: "));

 block = 2;
 //Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
 status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
 if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
   Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
   Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
   return;
 }

 // Write block
 status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(block, &buffer[16], 16);
 if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
   Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Write() failed: "));
   Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
   return;
 }
 else Serial.println(F("MIFARE_Write() success: "));

 // Ask personal data: First name
 Serial.println(F("Type First name, ending with #"));
 len = Serial.readBytesUntil('#', (char *) buffer, 20) ; // read first name from serial
 for (byte i = len; i < 20; i++) buffer[i] = ' ';     // pad with spaces

 block = 4;
 //Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
 status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
 if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
   Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
   Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
   return;
 }

 // Write block
 status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(block, buffer, 16);
 if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
   Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Write() failed: "));
   Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
   return;
  }
  else Serial.println(F("MIFARE_Write() success: "));

  block = 5;
  //Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
   }

   // Write block
   status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(block, &buffer[16], 16);
   if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
     Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Write() failed: "));
     Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
     return;
   }
   else Serial.println(F("MIFARE_Write() success: "));

   Serial.println(" ");
   mfrc522.PICC_HaltA(); // Halt PICC
   mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();  // Stop encryption on PCD
}
```

With the tag and card included in the module (RC522) this code works fine:

[image: Working code using card and tag]

With the NTAG213 sticker the code doesn't work:

[image: Non-working code using NTAG213 sticker]

I need to write data in this stickers, how can I do that?

Comment: I also tried to use this code, thank you for your answer but I would like to write data to NTAG213 NFC tags from serial monitor. First code (example code from libary) works with serial monitor. How we can write data from serial monitor?

Answer (score 2):

The one that comes with RC552 is MiFare Classic 1K

And the programming running is for the same.

Ntag213 is MiFare Ultralight C, which requires different type of programming..

Try this one

```
/* mifare ultralight example (25-02-2018)
 *
 *   RFID-RC522 (SPI connexion)
 *   
 *   CARD RC522      Arduino (UNO)
 *     SDA  -----------  10 (Configurable, see SS_PIN constant)
 *     SCK  -----------  13
 *     MOSI -----------  11
 *     MISO -----------  12
 *     IRQ  ----------- 
 *     GND  -----------  GND
 *     RST  -----------  9 (onfigurable, see RST_PIN constant)
 *     3.3V ----------- 3.3V
 *     
 */

  #include <SPI.h>
  #include <MFRC522.h>


  #define SS_PIN          10
  #define RST_PIN         6

  MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);  // Create MFRC522 instance
  MFRC522::StatusCode status; //variable to get card status

  byte buffer[18];  //data transfer buffer (16+2 bytes data+CRC)
  byte size = sizeof(buffer);

  uint8_t pageAddr = 0x06;  //In this example we will write/read 16 bytes (page 6,7,8 and 9).
                            //Ultraligth mem = 16 pages. 4 bytes per page. 
                            //Pages 0 to 4 are for special functions.           

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  SPI.begin(); // Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522 card 
  Serial.println(F("Sketch has been started!"));
  memcpy(buffer,"HELLO WORLD! ;-)",16);
}

void loop() {
  // Look for new cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
    return;

  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
    return;


  // Write data ***********************************************


  for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
    //data is writen in blocks of 4 bytes (4 bytes per page)
    status = (MFRC522::StatusCode) mfrc522.MIFARE_Ultralight_Write(pageAddr+i, &buffer[i*4], 4);
    if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
      Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Read() failed: "));
      Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
      return;
    }
  }
  Serial.println(F("MIFARE_Ultralight_Write() OK "));
  Serial.println();




  // Read data ***************************************************
  Serial.println(F("Reading data ... "));
  //data in 4 block is readed at once.
  status = (MFRC522::StatusCode) mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(pageAddr, buffer, &size);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Read() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }

  Serial.print(F("Readed data: "));
  //Dump a byte array to Serial
  for (byte i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    Serial.write(buffer[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();

}
```